# jwplayer slow buffer video lag

Tags: android, html, ffmpeg, video-streaming, jwplayer6

I’m using Jwplayer for my mobile site... So i need mobile capability html5 player.. i choose jwplayer.

I'm Converting Video with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i Input.mp4 -vcodec h264 -b 1400k -s 1280X720 -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ab 128k -movflags faststart -y Output.mp4
```

I'm Using Centos Apache server and so i installed H264 Streaming Module

My videos are starting fast at first.. but in middle when my internet slows and buffering slows down.. At the same time video lags and sounds continues for few second ... at some point my video and audio sync well. This is happening because of slow buffer problem.. After whole video buffered when i replay..full video is playing well . 
**I Used Some Android Phones Chrome Browser To Check .**
I need playing position to Show load Icon and wait if buffer slows.. not lag video

I cant lower my video bitrate.. because of my competitors.. i want solution for my html5 player.. i have added my jwplayer code.

```
<script>    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        width: "100%",
        skin: "skin.xml",
        autostart: true,

        sharing: {},
      image: "http://example.com/Mp4/screen.jpg",

      sources: [{
        file: "http://example.com/720.mp4",
        label: "720p",
        "default": "true"
      },{
        file: "http://example.com/HD/hd.mp4",
        label: "HD"
      },{
        file: "http://example.com/Mp4/480x320.mp4",
        label: "480p"
      }],
      startparam: "starttime",
        stretching: "exactfit",
        autostart: false,
    });



</script>
```